# Cannot Access Memory at Address c++

Tags: c++

In gdb, I'm getting a "Cannot access memory at address [ ]" The program, at the moment, runs fine but I'm perplexed why I cannot access it right.

http://hastebin.com/wulomoqimu - main.cpp

http://hastebin.com/hahosuruhe - player.h

These are, I believe the relevent files.

```
    *(playerNames+i) = (players+i) -> name;
    *(playerCards+i) = (players+i) -> hand;
    *(playerScores+i) = (players+i) -> score;
```

And some lines I'm not sure about. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not enough context to help you out.  Have you tried pulling this up in a debugger and looking around?  What is the value of those pointers and the values of `i`?  Also, any reason you're not using `playerNames[i] = players[i].name` for the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
playerNames = new string * [numPlayers];
```

`playerNames` is pointing to an array of string pointers. Which means you have allocated memory to pointers that can point to string objects. The array is filled with some garbage addresses as of now.

```
*(playerNames+i) = (players+i) -> name;
```

Here you are dereferencing with out array pointing to no valid string object addresses. You have to make each array index pointing to a valid memory address before dereferencing.

```
for( int i=0; i<numPlayers; ++i )
    playerNames[i] = new string();
```

Now the array is filled with valid string object addresses.